# How to pass a function as an argument of a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery plugin to show an alert box (custom html + css) and bind the yes an no buttons to functions passed as an argument of the plugins call.

Here's my code so far:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.triggerAlert = function (msg,yes,no) {
    $('#alert_mask').find("span:first").html(msg);
    $('#alert_mask').toggle();

    $('#alert_mask #alert_yes').click(function (yes) {
        if (typeof yes == 'function') { 
            yes($(this));
        }
        $('#alert_mask').hide();
        return false;       
    });

    $('#alert_mask #alert_no').click(function (no) {
        if (typeof no == 'function') { 
            no($(this));
        }
        $('#alert_mask').hide();
        return false;       
    });

}   
})(jQuery);
```

Is this in the right track or is it just plain wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE: after [Logan F. Smyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/logan-f-smyth) answer I had to make an ajustment because the click events of the yes and no buttons here being defined several times. For future reference or for someone else benefit here is the complete plugin.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.triggerAlert = function (trigger,msg,yes,no) {
    var mask = $('#alert_mask');
    $(trigger).click(function (e) {
        mask.find("span:first").html(msg);
        mask.toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#alert_yes').click(function (e) {
      if (yes) yes($(this));
      mask.hide();
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $('#alert_no').click(function (e) {
      if (no) no($(this));
      mask.hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }   
})(jQuery);
```

And an example of how to call it

```
 $().triggerAlert(
    $('#some_element'),
    'hello world',
    function() { alert('yes') },
    function() { alert('no')  }
  );
```

Comment: Not as I expected. I tested passing the alert function as arguments, and the alert is called as I call the plugin instead of in the click functions of the buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I see is that your click handlers take 'no' and 'yes' arguments, which means that inside of those functions, yes and no won't be what you passed to the overall plugin.

It's also unneccesary to have your selects use two ids, since ids are unique anyway. Finally return false is a bad idea, use preventDefault instead.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.triggerAlert = function (msg,yes,no) {
    var mask = $('#alert_mask');
    mask.find("span:first").html(msg);
    mask.toggle();

    $('#alert_yes').click(function (e) {
      if (yes) yes($(this));
      mask.hide();
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $('#alert_no').click(function (e) {
      if (no) no($(this));
      mask.hide();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }   
})(jQuery);
```

To trigger this, you would call the function and pass two functions like this:

```
$('#some_element').click(function(e){
  $(this).triggerAlert(
    'hello world',
    function() { alert('yes') },
    function() { alert('no')  }
  );
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Then how to I passed the functions to the click handler. If I don't set them as arguments the they are undefined when the click appends

Comment: A function can see all the variables in the functions that wrap around it, so they can see 'yes' and 'no' automatically. I've added some code to my answer. Also the 'this' passed to your callback is going to me the #alert_yes and no elements, not mask. is that what you want?

Comment: Thank for you interest but still the behavior is the same. and there is a part of your code that is not what I need. You're hiding and toggling an inner span that has the message, and I have to toggle an outter div.

Comment: You are right, the toggle part was incorrect. I've fixed it now. What other part isn't working? Can you show how you are actually calling this function with the arguments and such?

Comment: Just to test I'm setting the plugin on a click event like this `$('#some_element').click(function(){$(this).triggerAlert('hello world',alert('yes'),alert('no')); return false;})` And both alert() functions get called when I execute this on Firebug's console

Comment: In that, you are executing both `alert` functions, and then passing the result of those functions to your `triggerAlert` code. You need to pass functions that, when executed, will trigger the `alert`s. I have updated my answer with an example. Also, don't use `return false`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Now seeing the solution is obvious but I was banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

parameters are in the function scope, you can try like this

```
  $('#alert_mask #alert_no').click(function() {
    if (typeof no == 'function') { 
        no($(this));
    }
    $('#alert_mask').hide();
    return false;       
});
```

Comment: When the click happens no is undefined

Comment: How do you do initialization with triggerAlert

Comment: `$('#some_element').click(function(){$(this).triggerAlert('hello world',alert('yes'),alert('no')); return false;})`